# How put the Ktor log in a single line?

Tags: kotlin, logging, logback, ktor

I'm using `ktor-client-core:2.3.2` with the `ktor-client-logging:2.3.2` pluging and `ktor-client-logging:2.3.2`.

This is my `ktor` and `Logback.xml` configurations:

```kotlin
val httpClient = HttpClient(engine) {
        install(Logging) {
            level = LogLevel.INFO
        }
    }
```

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight(%-5level) --- [%25.25thread]  %cyan(%-36.36logger): %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

The output in my console is this:

```
2023-07-11 16:34:00.370 INFO  --- [her-worker-1 @coroutine#1]  io.ktor.client.HttpClient           : REQUEST: http://localhost:1234/test
METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST) 
2023-07-11 16:34:01.004 INFO  --- [her-worker-3 @coroutine#1]  io.ktor.client.HttpClient           : RESPONSE: 200 OK
METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
```

Is it possible to put the `Ktor` logs in a single line (the `METHOD` block should not go in a new line)?

I expect something like this:

```
2023-07-11 16:34:00.370 INFO  --- [her-worker-1 @coroutine#1]  io.ktor.client.HttpClient           : REQUEST: http://localhost:1234/test METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST) 
2023-07-11 16:34:01.004 INFO  --- [her-worker-3 @coroutine#1]  io.ktor.client.HttpClient           : RESPONSE: 200 OK METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
```

Is there some way to change the `Ktor` logging pattern?

Comment: You can use your logger implementation when installing the `Logging` plugin, but changing the Ktor logging pattern that way would be challenging.

Answer (score 0):

You are using logback and if you want to customize your logs you can do it in `logback.xml` file you provided.

Other way is to use `CallLogging` [plugin](https://ktor.io/docs/call-logging.html) where you can customize your logs.

```
install(CallLogging) {
  format { ... }
}
```

However this looks more like your IDE is wrapping logs. If you are using IntelliJ IEDA, you can change it in logs sidebar by disabling `soft-wrap`. For any other IDE it should be similar.

[image]